# How to prevent disabled Button from going behind another ImageView or Button?

Tags: android, xml, image, android-layout

EDIT: After more testing, I believe that the problem mentioned below is occuring on click, not on disable. Researching into elevation, to see if in click possibly changes that.

I am using a constraint layout and I have two buttons that contain images. 
One of them is disabled temporarily or permanently when clicked by the user. 
The problem? The second button (which should stay at the back) ends up covering the other newly disabled button. 
I've tried searching for anything concerning this but couldn't find anything to help me solve this. I've also tried using an ImageView for the button that should stay underneath, but also didn't work.

```
// the button that should stay underneath 
<Button
        android:id="@+id/bg_pup_img"
        android:contentDescription="@string/pup2_desc"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd"
        android:background="@drawable/pup2"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/end_game"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.5" />

// the button I want to stay at the top
<Button
        android:id="@+id/card19"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blank_card"
        android:tag="19"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/card15" />
```

Comment: it will be good if you would have added your whole xml layout. In that way we could help you more freely.

Answer (score 0):

> Try adding android:visibility="" to 'gone' or 'invisible'

Making you button disable will put it to background.

Comment: But won't that make it so you can't see the button? I still want both buttons to be visible, with the second one mentioned in the code above to lay on top of the bigger button.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood right , you want to show a button when a user click another one , if this is the case , why don't you make the second button "invisible" after the user clicks

Comment: No. So what I have is one bigger unclickable, disabled button with an image in the back. And multiple smaller buttons in front of that one bigger button. My problem right now is that the smaller buttons go behind the bigger one either after I click it or disable it (I actually need to reconfirm whether it is on click or on disable since I am doubting this now).

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have fixed my problem. 
I'm not exactly sure how elevation works on click, but when ever I clicked the "top" button, it would go below the "bottom" button. 
I made the elevation of the "bottom" button to be 0dp while the "top" button is 1dp. Now I no longer have that problem.